# Azure Web Jobs what happens after deployment web sites?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have on azure web sites and have several web jobs on this VM. And some times I updated web sites (from GitHub) but not web jobs. And me interesting what happens with my web jobs after deployment web sites? He stopping or restarting after deployment or if I not updated web jobs he working remainder unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying your site shouldn't affect, or restart, your running webjobs.

You can easily verify that by looking at the webjob PID from Process Explorer at `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer` during the deployment.

The only time your webjobs will be restarted is if you update them or if the whole site is restarting for other reasons (e.g: config update, moving VMs, manual restart, etc)